# Метод ForEach и IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, дизайн-языка

Подскажите, а в чем мотивация того, что этот метод работает только с `List<T>`? Ведь `IEnumerable` тоже имеет все необходимое.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ок, подправил. Тем не менее, все равно интересует, почему его нету на уровне IEnumirable.

Comment: А мотивация в том, что `IEnumerable` и `Linq` это фича из ФП и всё это *чистые* функции, не имеющие побочных эффектов. ForEach в эту чистоту не вписывается. https://stackoverflow.com/a/200614/6766879

Comment: А что значит ФП?

Comment: Функциональное Программирование же

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Многие люди спрашивают меня, почему Microsoft не сделал для коллекций метод расширения `ForEach`. У класса `List<T>` уже есть такой метод, но почему не добавить такой метод для всех последовательностей. Практически - это однострочник:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action)
{ 
    // argument null checking omitted
    foreach(T item in sequence) action(item);
}
```

Обычно на вопрос: "Почему X не реализовано?" я отвечаю, что [любая особенность не реализована](http://blog.ryjones.org/2005/07/12/product-development/), пока кто-то ее не спроектирует, реализует, протестирует, и предоставит. И никто не даст денег на это. И да, хотя я отмечал, что [даже самые маленькие особенности могут иметь большую стоимость](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx), конкретно эта по настоящему простая, очевидная, легко тестируемая и легко документируемая. Стоимость всегда имеет значение, но в этом случае она незначительна.

С другой стороны, если это так просто, почему бы не сделать это самому, если так нужно? И по настоящему важна тут не низкая стоимость, а полученная выгода. Дальше будет видно, что я считаю выгоду здесь также небольшой, если вообще не отрицательной. Но мы должны посмотреть немного глубже. У меня есть две причины против этого метода.

Первая причина заключается в том, что это нарушает принципы функционального программирования, на которых основаны остальные операторы для последовательностей. Очевидно, что **цель этого метода - вызвать побочные эффекты**. Цель выражения (expression) - вычислить значение, а не получить побочный эффект. Получение побочного эффекта - это цель для `statement`. Его вызов выглядит как выражение (expression) (хотя, надо признать, что, так как метод возвращает `void`, выражение может быть использовано только в контексте "statement expression"). Меня не устраивает делать единственный оператор только для последовательностей, который будет использоваться только для побочных эффектов.

Вторая причина заключается в том, что это ничего не добавляет языку. И сделав это можно будет переписать совершенно чистую строку кода

```
foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
```

в следующую

```
foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });
```

которая использует почти те же символы в немного другом порядке. Кроме того, вторая версия тяжелее для понимания, отладки, вводит семантику замыканий, что в некоторых случаях может поменять время жизни объекта.

Когда мы предоставляем два похожих способа сделать одно и то же, мы вносим путаницу в индустрии, становится тяжелее читать код друг друга и т.д. Иногда выгода от наличия двух разный текстовых представлений для одной операции (например, query-синтаксис vs method-синтаксис или `+` vs `String.Concat`) настолько огромна, что можно пренебречь потенциальной путаницей. Но убедительное преимущество `query` выражений - их читаемость; новая форма `foreach` читается определенно не лучше, а может быть даже и хуже.

Если вы не согласны с такими философскими возражениями и видите практическую ценность в таком шаблоне, идите и напишите этот однострочник сами.

<sub>Перевод [блога @EricLippert](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)</sub>

Comment: О, а ты целиком статью перевёл :) Только перевод какой-то кривоватый (((

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, я там в нескольких местах не смог подобрать, а в некоторых наверное не точно перевел, можешь поправить?

Answer (score 5):

1. Этот метод нужен только для side-эффектов, что противоречит функциональной концепции linq.
2. Этот метод не ведёт к сокращению кода:

   ```
   foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
   foos.ForEach((Foo foo)=>{ statement involving foo; });
   ```

   получились почти те же символы, но в несколько другом порядке. К тому же вторую версию сложнее понять, сложнее отладить и в ней появляется замыкание, которое может повлиять на время жизни объектов.

Но каждый, кто не согласен с этими философскими причинами и видит пользу в этом паттерне, - вперёд! Просто реализуйте этот тривиальный однострочник самостоятельно.

Источник: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Comment: По длине кода - с тех пор язык научился выводить тип для параметра лямбды, так что второй вариант будет короче

Comment: @PashaPash, на три символа :)

Answer (score 4):

До .net 4.5 разница была во внутренней реализации:

`foreach` внутри реализовался(и реализуется) через итератор. Это означает что все завалится как только убрать из списка один элемент. Зато работает быстрее.

`ForEach()` же **БЫЛ** внутри реализован через `for(int i=0; i<list.Count, i++)`

и это давало нам возможность сделать вот так:

```
someList.ForEach(x => { 
    if(x.RemoveMe) someList.Remove(x); 
});
```

**Начиная с .net 4.5 оба метода работают через итератор и являются взаимозаменяемыми.** Просто разный синтаксис использования.

Информация взята с: https://stackoverflow.com/a/226082/4423545

---

Так же нашлась статья  [Eric Lipperts blog "foreach" vs "ForEach"](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) -- а он -- *principal developer on the C# compiler team*. Думаю, что там можно нарыть какую-то дополнительную информацию.

На сколько я понял, ForEach оставили только листу и не привязывали всем IEnumerable что бы не плодить:

```
foos.ForEach((Foo foo) => { 
    statement involving foo; 
}); // сложно для понимания при беглом взгляде
```

а что бы люди писали:

```
foreach(Foo foo in foos)
{ 
    statement involving foo; 
}// легко для понимания
```

И даже в 1 строку читается все равно проще:

```
foreach(Foo foo in foos){ statement involving foo; }
```

Comment: Что-то все 3 куска кода в первой части ответа выглядят неработающими. Точнее, в первом просто баг - попробуй `if (true)`, а два других - просто не взлетят - проверь вывод.