# Cтупенчатый массив и LINQ

Tags: c#

Задание:
В каждой 4 строке посчитать произведение положительных. Если строк меньше 4, взять по умолчанию строчку содержащую элементы 1,2,3,4,5. А если нет положительных, то произведение считать нулевым и взять сумму по всем строкам.

```
int[][] numbers = new int[4][];
numbers[0] = new int[] { 3, 2 };
numbers[1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
numbers[2] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
numbers[3] = new int[] { 1, 1, 3, 3, 2 };
```

Примерно код должен быть похож, но я не знаю как проверить есть ли в строчке данные элементы 1,2,3,4,5 и как подсчитать сумму по всем строка, если условие не подойдет.

```
int[] result = (numbers.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(numbers, x) % 4 == 0
     ? numbers.Sum(z => z.Count(y => y > 0)) == numbers.Sum(z => z.Count())
    ? numbers.Sum(z => z.Count(y => y > 0)) : -1 : -1 ))
     .Where(x => x != -1)
     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Он не вывод исключений, он вообще ничего не выводит

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, что-то такое:

```
numbers
  .Where((x, i) => i % 4 == 3)
  .DefaultIfEmpty(numbers.Where(a => Enumerable.Range(1, 5).All(x => a.Contains(x))).FirstOrDefault())
  .Select(a => a?.Aggregate(1, (x, y) => x * y) ?? numbers.Sum(a => a.Sum()))
```

Comment: я извиняюсь, но как это все вывести в консоль. .ForEach(val => Console.WriteLine(val)); не работает.

Comment: .ForEach есть только у списков - используй нормальный.

Comment: В плане нормальный? Можно пример, если вас не затруднит?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915389/178988